# Issue with my bash script to copy files

Tags: bash

I have written a bash file to copy files from a folder to another folder.

```
cp -u "{Source}" "{Destination}"
```

The above one is my bash file.

The problem now is, if I give the `Destination = k`,then also,the bash file get executed(Normally in the `destination` we will give the path) and it's giving success message.It's giving success message but It's not copying file and it's just creating a file in the name `k`(k mean,I gave the destination as k above)

So I need to check the destination and if the destination is not properly given,I need to give error message.How to do it?

Comment: You're missing the "$" characters in your script?

Comment: Don't invent your own syntax. Read the manuel https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html. Neither your assignment nor your parameter expansion is syntactically correct.

Comment: Wil it validate?how can I include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if [ -d "${Destination}" ]; then
    # do the copy work
else
    # echo the error message
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `if [ -d "$k" ]; then
    cp -u "/home/Desktop/test.txt" "k"
else
    # echo the error message
    exit 1
fi`

Comment: but when we call variable only ,we will cal $ know?how the $ sign will check for the destination here?

Comment: @acer No, don't do `"$k"` because ${variable} accesses the content of the variable. If you have assigned 'k'(the content) to Destination(the variable), then you simply use ${Destination}. `[ -d "${Destination}" ]` checks if 'k' is an directory on your disk.

Comment: it's working fine,thank you.May I know,what's the different between `-z` and `-d` in bash file

Comment: @acer Well, you can google "linux test command", which does the same thing as `[]` in shell scripts. That means, `test -d file` in shell commands equals to `[ -d file ]` in shell scripts. While `test -z string` checks if the string is empty, `test -d file` checks if the file exists and is a directory.